# conversion of dec to hexadecimal with leading zero using leading zero's

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using the below function to convert dec to hex:
where p_base = 16.

The issue is the below function wont support leading zero scenario, it will remove the leading zero
which is causing as issue.

My excepted result: The output hex number should be 5 digit and it should not ignore leading zero's of provided decimal.

```
create or replace FUNCTION       to_base (p_dec IN NUMBER, p_base IN NUMBER)
   RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
   l_str   VARCHAR2 (255) DEFAULT NULL;
   l_num   NUMBER         DEFAULT p_dec;
   l_hex   VARCHAR2 (16)  DEFAULT '0123456789abcdef';
BEGIN
   IF (p_dec IS NULL OR p_base IS NULL)
   THEN
      RETURN NULL;
   END IF;

   IF (TRUNC (p_dec) <> p_dec OR p_dec < 0)
   THEN
      RAISE PROGRAM_ERROR;
   END IF;

   LOOP
      l_str := SUBSTR (l_hex, MOD (l_num, p_base) + 1, 1) || l_str;
      l_num := TRUNC (l_num / p_base);
      EXIT WHEN (l_num = 0);
   END LOOP;
  dbms_output.put_line(l_str);
   RETURN l_str;
END to_base;
```

Comment: "it should not ignore leading zero's of provided decimal." A `NUMBER` data type does not have a format and **CANNOT** have leading zeroes; when you write `00012` it will be stored as the binary value of the decimal `12` and the fact that you wrote `000` before is lost. Please [edit] your question to explain what you mean by leading zeroes because you appear to be asking for the function to consider data that it will never be given. If you want to have leading zeroes then you need to pass a `VARCHAR2` data type and not a `NUMBER` data type into the function for `p_dec`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using FOR LOOP instead of LOOP, the output hex number can be always 5 digit.

```sql
   FOR i IN 1..5 LOOP
      l_str := SUBSTR (l_hex, MOD (l_num, p_base) + 1, 1) || l_str;
      l_num := TRUNC (l_num / p_base);
   END LOOP;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b64acd/2)

Comment: @user2907032 This will not accurately represent outputs with more than 5 digits. Try `TO_BASE( 32, 2 )` and you will find it outputs `00000`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `LPAD` according to your needs:

```
LPAD(to_base(20, 16), 5,'0')
```

BTW, for conversion into HEX you can use built-in function. My function for this is this one:

```
FUNCTION Dec2Base(DecN IN NUMBER, Base IN INTEGER DEFAULT 16) RETURN VARCHAR2 DETERMINISTIC IS
    
    BaseString VARCHAR2(129) := NULL;
    DecNumber NUMBER := DecN;
    HexString CONSTANT CHAR(16) := '0123456789ABCDEF';
    
BEGIN
    IF DecN IS NULL THEN
        RETURN NULL;
    ELSIF Base NOT IN (2, 8, 16) THEN 
        RAISE VALUE_ERROR;
    ELSIF base = 16 THEN
        RETURN TO_CHAR(DecN, 'fmXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
    ELSE
        IF DecN > 2**127 THEN
            -- "MOD(DecNumber, Base)" returns wrong result for larger numbers
            RAISE NUMERIC_OVERFLOW;
        END IF;         
        LOOP
            BaseString := SUBSTR(HexString, MOD(DecNumber, Base) + 1, 1 ) || BaseString;
            DecNumber := TRUNC(DecNumber / Base);
            EXIT WHEN DecNumber = 0;
        END LOOP;
        RETURN BaseString;
    END IF;
    
END Dec2Base;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement of "it should not ignore leading zero's of provided decimal" is unclear as a `NUMBER` data type cannot have leading zeroes so I am assuming that you are actually providing a string with a formatted number that can be left-padded with zeroes and the output required is an accurate representation of the input value in the new base with at least as many digits as the input number (and a minimum of 5).

You can use:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION TO_BASE(
  p_dec IN  VARCHAR2,
  p_base IN PLS_INTEGER
) RETURN VARCHAR2 DETERMINISTIC
IS
   l_str             VARCHAR2 (255) DEFAULT NULL;
   l_num             PLS_INTEGER;
   p_max_base_digits PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
   IF (  p_dec IS NULL
      OR p_base IS NULL )
   THEN
      RETURN NULL;
   END IF;
   
   -- Check that p_dec is a valid decimal.
   FOR i IN 1 .. LENGTH( p_dec ) LOOP
     IF SUBSTR( p_dec, i, 1 ) NOT BETWEEN '0' AND '9' THEN
       RETURN NULL;
     END IF;
   END LOOP;

   IF p_base NOT BETWEEN 2 AND 16 THEN
     RETURN NULL;
   END IF;

   l_num := TO_NUMBER( p_dec );
   
   -- The output should have a number of digits that is the greater of either:
   -- a) the number of digits as in the decimal input value;
   -- b) the number of digits required to accurately express the decimal input
   --    value in the new base; or
   -- c) 5 digits.
   p_max_base_digits := GREATEST(
     CEIL( LOG( p_base, l_num ) ) + 1,
     LENGTH( p_dec ),
     5
   );

   -- Generate each digit in the new base
   FOR i IN 1 .. p_max_base_digits LOOP
      l_str := TO_CHAR( MOD( l_num, p_base ), 'fmX' ) || l_str;
      l_num := TRUNC (l_num / p_base);
   END LOOP;

   RETURN l_str;
END to_base;
/
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE inputs ( value VARCHAR2(20) );

BEGIN
  INSERT INTO inputs ( value ) VALUES ( '32' );
  INSERT INTO inputs ( value ) VALUES (  00000032  );
  INSERT INTO inputs ( value ) VALUES ( '00000032' );
END;
/
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT value,
       TO_BASE( value, 2 ) AS b2,
       TO_BASE( value, 3 ) AS b3,
       TO_BASE( value, 4 ) AS b4,
       TO_BASE( value, 5 ) AS b5,
       TO_BASE( value, 6 ) AS b6,
       TO_BASE( value, 7 ) AS b7,
       TO_BASE( value, 8 ) AS b8,
       TO_BASE( value, 9 ) AS b9,
       TO_BASE( value, 10 ) AS b10,
       TO_BASE( value, 11 ) AS b11,
       TO_BASE( value, 12 ) AS b12,
       TO_BASE( value, 13 ) AS b13,
       TO_BASE( value, 14 ) AS b14,
       TO_BASE( value, 15 ) AS b15,
       TO_BASE( value, 16 ) AS b16
FROM   inputs;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> VALUE    | B2       | B3       | B4       | B5       | B6       | B7       | B8       | B9       | B10      | B11      | B12      | B13      | B14      | B15      | B16     
> :------- | :------- | :------- | :------- | :------- | :------- | :------- | :------- | :------- | :------- | :------- | :------- | :------- | :------- | :------- | :-------
> 32       | 100000   | 01012    | 00200    | 00112    | 00052    | 00044    | 00040    | 00035    | 00032    | 0002A    | 00028    | 00026    | 00024    | 00022    | 00020   
> 32       | 100000   | 01012    | 00200    | 00112    | 00052    | 00044    | 00040    | 00035    | 00032    | 0002A    | 00028    | 00026    | 00024    | 00022    | 00020   
> 00000032 | 00100000 | 00001012 | 00000200 | 00000112 | 00000052 | 00000044 | 00000040 | 00000035 | 00000032 | 0000002A | 00000028 | 00000026 | 00000024 | 00000022 | 00000020
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=286c407f1114345abfb7360fb619bb76)*